# Translating sequential code into openMP parallel construct

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I have the following piece of code that I would like to write in openmp.

My code abstractly looks like the following

I start first with dividing `N=100` iterations equally among `p=10`pieces and I store the allocated iterations for every piece in a vector

```
Nvec[1]={0,1,..,9}
Nvec[2]={10,11,..,19}
Nvec[p]={N-9,..,N}
```

then I loop on the iterations

```
for(k=0;k<p;k++){\\loop on each piece of Nvec
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){\\here is a nested loop
        for(i=Nvec[k][0];i<Nvec[k][p];i++){
            \\then I loop between the first and 
            \\last value of the array corresponding to piece k
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see the code is sequential with a total of `2*100=200 iterations`, I wanted to parallelize it using OpenMp with the absolute condition to keep the order of iterations!

I tried the following

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) collapse(2)
{
for(j=0;j<2;j++){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        \\loop code here
    }
}
}
```

this setting doesn't keep the order of the iterations as in the sequential version.
In the sequential version, each chunk is processed entirely with `j=0` and then entirely with `j=1`.

In my openMP version, every thread takes a chunk of iterations and process it entirely with `j=0`. In a way all threads treats either `j=0` or `j=1` cases. Every worker with `p=10` processes `200/10=20 iterations`, problem is all iterations are `j=0 or j=1`.

How can I make sure that every thread get a chunk of iterations, performs the loop code with `j=0` on **all** the iterations, then `j=1` on the same chunk of iterations?

EDIT

what I want exactly for every chunk of 20 iterations

```
worker 1
j:0
i:1--->10
j:1
i:1--->10
worker p
j:0
i:90--->99
j:1
i:90--->99
```

the openMP code above does

```
worker 1
j:0
i:1--->20
worker p
j:1
i:80--->99
```

Comment: can you not change the order of the loops, i.e. make the outer loop for `i` and the inner loop for `j`?

Comment: yes, in that case every iteration `i` gets successively `j=0` and `j=1`. I am interested in having `j=0` for all iterations in the chunk **then** `j=1` on the same iterations. The order is important for speed purposes relative to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simple - just make the outer `j`-loop non-worksharing:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         ...
    }
}
```

If you use the `static` schedule, OpenMP guarantees, that each worker will get to handle the same range of `i`s for both `j=0` and `j=1`.

Note: You moving the `parallel` construct to the outer loop is merely an optimization to avoid thread management overhead. The code works similarly if you just place a `parallel for` in-between the two loops.

Comment: Great, thanks! is there any way to guarantee the order in a dynamic schedule?

Comment: @Marouen What do you mean by "guarantee the order". Of course a dynamic schedule will not guarantee the equal distribution of indices for successive loops. That would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: The default schedule is implementation-dependent, not `static`.

Comment: @Zulan here is my question: using dynamic schedule, is there a way to to tell each worker to process a chunk of iterations `i` in a way that `j=0` for all the iterations of the chunk then `j=1`

Comment: @Marouen I can't think of anything right now short of recording all indices `i` during the `j=0` loop and then manually replaying that index sequence.